# Using data from django queries in the same view

Tags: python, django

I might have missed somthing while searching through the documentation - I can't seem to find a way to use data from one query to form another query.

My query is:

```
sites_list = Site.objects.filter(worker=worker)
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for site in sites_list:
    [Insert Query Here]
```

Edit: I saw the awnser and im not sure how i didnt get that, maybe thats the sign im up too late coding :S

Comment: "Something like this" is a bit vague. What is it exactly that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily do something like this:

```
sites_list = Site.objects.filter(worker=worker)

for site in sites_list:
    new_sites_list = Site.objects.filter(name=site.name).filter(something else)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `__in` lookup type. For example, if you had an `Entry` model with a relation to `Site`, you could write:

```
Entry.objects.filter(site__in=Site.objects.filter(...some conditions...))
```

This will end up doing one query in the DB (the filter condition on sites would be turned into a subquery in the `WHERE` clause).